# JWT Silent Refreshing based on Redis - MERN Stack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redis, jwt

I've been struggling so long with silent refreshing to make it the most transparent to client.

I've implemented so many strategies so far and still I have no clue how solve it fully.

When I perform silent refreshing I put my recent generated refresh token in redis db for further access token generation so as to it carries out refreshing for both everytime when there is a need to refresh.

Due to React Strict Mode in dev mode, request is being made twice so first time it can be pulled out from db and showed normally but consecutive request acts like value in db doesn't exist and it spits null value.

My middleware is written in express js, I put my code beneath:

```
const authRefresh = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const refreshToken = await req.cookies['refresh-token'];
        const accessToken = await req.cookies['access-token'];

        if (!refreshToken) {
            return res.status(401).json({ status: 'error', message: "Refresh token not found" })
        }

        if (!accessToken || accessToken.includes('mockup'))
            jwt.verify(refreshToken, process.env.JWT_REFRESH, async (err, userProperties) => {

                if (err) {
                    return res.status(401).json(err)
                }

                const redisValue = await redisClient.get(refreshToken);

                if (redisValue) {
                    const tokens = await generateToken(userProperties)

                    //setting tokens in httpOnly cookies
                    res.cookie('access-token', tokens.accessToken,
                        cookiesTime.access);
                    res.cookie('refresh-token', tokens.refreshToken,
                        cookiesTime.refresh);

                    await redisClient.del(redisValue);
                    await redisClient.set(tokens.refreshToken, tokens.refreshToken);
                    await redisClient.expire(tokens.refreshToken, time_refresh);

                    return res.status(200).json('Tokens set again')
                }
                else {
                    return res.status(401).json('No refresh token in db');
                }
            })
        else return res.status(202).json('No need to refresh an access token')

    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(401).json({ status: 'error', message: err })
    }
}
```

PS. I want to mention I've tried rearrange redis methods from asynchronous to synchronous and backwards. It seems the same for my action.